# Run PHP script in crontab only works when exporting to a file

Tags: php, linux, centos, cron

On CentOS release 6.5 (Final):

I know that usually I just need to use the following command in crontab to run a php script.

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php absolute_path_file_to_the_script.php
```

But, recently, it stopped working. The only work around is to use the following command

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php absolute_path_file_to_the_script.php > log
```

But I would rather not to output anything to log for now.

So, I even tried

```
0 * * * * /bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/php absolute_path_file_to_the_script.php"
```

But the above commend is again not working in crontab (it works if I type in the shell directly).

And I am sure that the above command did run in crontab for a second with 
`ps ux`, and then it stopped executing.

Any ideas on how to run the command properly without logging?

Comment: so `> /dev/null`, so the "log" gets tossed immediately?

Comment: Add "> /dev/null 2>&1" to the end to clear the output instead of "log"

Comment: What function does the php script perform?  Is it supposed to output to a file, update a database, or run server maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers from Marc and Greg work:

```
> /dev/null
```

or

```
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run that command (only php, without cron settings) from terminal and show result

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If I run the command directly from the terminal. It prints out help messages  such as the progress of program. In addition, it is also updating a mongo database.